# CRUD operation in c++ class hierarchy in tree format

Tags: c++, crud

I do have object hierarchy (object model) in tree format , where root class will have 2 child objects and these 2 child objects will have again other child objects. Now I need to implement a utility so that I can traverse entire tree and retrieve the object properties . Apart from this I should be able to add/delete the objects in tree , so basically I am looking for here CRUD operations (create, retrieve, update, delete).
below is basic implementation of the code with simple hierarchy but with this approach I am not able to perform CRUD operation as I believe object needs to be stored in tree structure format so that on the fly object model can be modified any property within hierarchy can be set/get in object. can anybody suggest better approach for the same so that object values can be persist in file.

```
Device
 | 
sensor
 |
------------------------
 |      |              |
dlidar stereo camera   GPS
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ThreedLidar
{
bool m_alarm;
public:

//set the properties
void set_alarm(bool set_val)
{

    m_alarm=set_val;
}   

//get the properties
bool get_alarm()
{
    return m_alarm;
}
};

struct Sensor
{
ThreedLidar dlidar; 

};
struct Device
{   
Sensor sensor;  

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Device device1;
    device1.sensor.dlidar.set_alarm(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There really isn't anything wrong with your code.  Ask your question in a clearer way...

Comment: I was asking about the approach how to store this objects in file so that on the fly object can be added/deleted/updated and properties can be set.

Comment: I was asking about the approach how to create a link to set and get the property  so that parent and child  relationship can be known on the fly. on the fly object can be added/deleted/updated and properties can be set.in given code there is only one object is created. I think object value needs to be  specified in the container  with parent child relationship so that dynamically entire tree can be built and i should be able to perform CURD operation on this tree .

Comment: Sensor struct can contain other class object as well like camera and GPS.